# VBA Export as PDF and Save to Location with name as per a Cell in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I recorded a macro to export as a PDF and it will save as the name I give it which is ok.

However when it’s saved the next time it overwrites the previous save.

I set up a Cell “S2” that displays the file location and file & current date & time

How can I use VBA to export and to use cell S2 as the location/filename.

Thanks

I recorded the macro as mentioned above

Comment: You need to include the code you tried if you want anyone to look at this

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code that gets generated when you record macro to export excel to pdf.

Recorded Code :

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\users\Desktop\macros\filename.pdf", Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Update Code to get the filename from cell S2:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    **Range("S2").Value** & ".pdf", Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Hope this answers your question. pls vote if it does.

Thanks,
Rajendra